# Is there an automatic way to generate a list of interface changes?

Tags: java

I am developing/maintaining a Java library, and would like to keep track of backwards-incompatible changes between releases. This list could contain changes in class declarations, method signatures etc.

For example, if I (accidentally) changed a constructor by adding a parameter, then I would like to have it included in the list and be warned about the change.

```
// before
public MyCar(String name) { ... }

// after (some accidental change)
public MyCar(String name, long mileage) { ... }
// an application using my library depending on this constructor would be broken
// when it updates to the new version
```

Is there an automated way to generate this list? It feels like something that IntelliJ or Gradle should be able to do.

My team has tried reviewing pull requests and maintaining a CHANGELOG manually (which seems to be a common approach), but that's prone to human errors. I seek an automated way that can ideally be part of the build system.

Comment: I guess I can add a line describing "what has been done so far to solve it." If you think this will attract spam, then point out an obvious answer.

Comment: You may want to look into the [animal sniffer project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer/index.html)

Comment: What about using a version control system? With git for example, a "git log" will give you the list of all the commits so if your commit messages are clear, it can work as a change log.

Comment: @VincentDurmont we try, but humans are too fallible.

Comment: Instead of changing method signature why don't you use method overloading?

Comment: @eatSleepCode Yes, that would be the correct way to introduce such a change. However, I want a way to catch mistakes when we make them. Pull requests are good but not bullet-proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always maintained the compatibility list manually but sometimes I forget something.

A quick look around shows several open source libraries but they haven't had new versions released in nearly 10 years.  So I don't know if they would work with new Java 7 or 8 features.

Note: I've never used any of these!

[CLIRR](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/project-info.html) - apache project used by some other apache projects to show what has changed (example output from apache commons-lang [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/clirr-report.html). last updated in 2005 doesn't even build with Maven 2 (or 3)

[JDiff](http://www.jdiff.org/) javadoc doclet comparator.  Might support Java 5. Last updated in 2008

[Japitools](http://sab39.netreach.com/Software/Japitools/Download/43/) - apparently was used by the GNU Classpath project to compare their APIs for signature compatibility with different versions of the Sun Java class libraries. Doesn't look like it's been updated since 2006

Comment: If CLIRR works, that would be awesome. Will try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to do it.

**Preserve backwards compatibility for a time** by annotating your methods with `@Deprecated`, and indicate when they'll be unsupported.  Then add the `@deprecated` piece to your Javadoc and that will [automatically generate a list of deprecated features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html) that the end user needs to care about.

This has the added benefit of allowing you to introduce when a feature was introduced (`@since`), and when a feature will be removed, without having to fuss *too* much with a lot of other tools.

Since you've added a more concrete code example, I'll add one more note:  those sorts of changes...are the result of a conscious design decision, and it brings to the forefront two issues:

- Regression testing (as in, a test should have caught this)
- Ease of transition into the newer API (as in, if I need to suddenly give a new parameter to this to gain functionality, isn't it a new thing rather than it being attached to the old, legacy thing?)

Those issues can't be teased away with any conventional tools; that requires an earnest conversation about the amount of time it takes to transition from one API to another.  If you find that you need to introduce new functionality to the core, then you had better make darn certain that hasn't broken the legacy case.

This is what it means to have an API - you **have** to have the older version lurking around for a while.

Comment: You would still have the same problem as OP when you eventually remove the deprecated methods

Comment: Not necessarily.  If building the Javadoc is part of the release/build step, it will be reflected in each build.

Comment: @Makoto I agree with you, but I also want a way to prevent myself from mistakenly changing the interface. This is more important in a larger team.

Comment: @Makoto I agree that you can get a list of deprecated methods from javadoc but you won't be able to see when methods disappear or their signatures change without comparing to a previous state

Comment: @JimLim: Elaborate on this, as a mistake in changing the interface usually leads to code that doesn't compile.  My approach is more documentation-centric, and forces a stronger coding discipline.  If you mark a method as `@Deprecated`, then you should be getting compiler warnings from it.

Comment: @dkatzel:  If a deprecated method was removed, why should I care?  It's the developer's responsibility to both continually update their library packages and pay attention to compiler warnings.  It's also a release issue as well; adequate time (maybe 6 to 8 weeks) needs to be given to ensure that all consumers are on the new API before the old one is purged.

Comment: Thanks for that @JimLim.  So, I'd say my recommendation still stands; deprecate and introduce functionality in a slower manner.  If you believe that someone is still using the old constructor, you should have regression tests that catch misbehavior with the new constructor, in order to fully smooth out the transition between different API versions.

Comment: Since classes aren't as concrete as an `interface`, I'd expect them to change, but if it's something that's being exposed to the end user and highly volatile, then there may be a slightly larger issue than just keeping track of all of the methods changing - it's that they're changing too quickly and in a way that the developers can't effectively keep up with or prepare for.